# Script to separate an object's mesh without using bpy.ops

Tags: python, scripting, mesh, bmesh

I've seen several posts suggesting that it's better to write functions that
manipulate bpy.data directly, instead of using the bpy.ops operators. I can
understand the argument about how operators such as bpy.ops.mesh.separate() are
meant for the user interface, requiring context such as the active object or the
mode (object vs. edit), usually given by the user.

But the operators are convenient because they embody so much of Blender's
functionality already, and I don't want to have to re-code that from
scratch... So where I can find this functionality in Blender's API, apart from
the bpy.ops operators ? Is it in bmesh ?

Here's a specific example : if I want to code the equivalent of "separate", I need (among
other things) to identify, in the set of vertices that I want to separate, which
ones are on the 'borders', so I can duplicate them. This would probably involve
navigating around the mesh data, iterating over each vertex's neighbors, and
checking whether they're inside my set. Not trivial for a newbie. So is there a
function for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently the only method for splitting objects uses `bpy.ops`, there aren't always API equivalents for each blender operator.

Comment: Isn't bmesh module able of re-creating the functionality? It will probably be slower than the operator, it should be possible to implement however.

Comment: Its possible to write in bmesh, and fairly fast since bmesh has connectivity data, but functionality doesn't exist out-of-the-box.